# Check if AsyncTask parameter is null

Tags: android, android-asynctask, indexoutofboundsexception

I have an async task for an activity that's executed on startup. If the user picks a location manually that url includes a value that's passed in as a parameter to the asynctask, and if the user doesn't dictate a location, the async task uses a default url. My problem is that I can't call `url[0]` on my code if a parameter was not specified. Is there a way to check and see if a parameter was passed into the async task? Below is my attempt. I've tried `url[0].isEmpty()` and `url[0] == null` but both give me `IndexOutOfBounds` error.

```
private class CallDestination extends AsyncTask<String, Void, JSONObject>{
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String...url){

            String MYURL = "";

            if(url[0].isEmpty()){
                MYURL = "http://thevisitapp.com/api/destinations/read?identifiers=10011";
            } else{
                MYURL = "http://thevisitapp.com/api/destinations/read?identifiers=" + url[0];
            }
            //TODO make this dynamic as it's passed in from other activity through intent


            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            return request.getJSONFromUrl(MYURL);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `if(url.length ==0)` to check if it's null!

Answer (score 1):

You can check if a parameter has been provided or not this way:

```
if(url == null)
```

You get the **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** when checking `if(url[0].length == 0)` because `url` is `null`, which basically means that the array contains 0 elements, which also means that you can't access `url[0]` as it would be considered **out of range**.

Answer (score 0):

Did you know that `String...` in `String... url` is an array? Therefore, you can implement several level of check:

1. Check if `url` is empty:

   ```
   if(url.length() == 0){
       //error, no URL given
   }
   ```
2. Check if `url` has value, but null:

   ```
   if(url[0] == null){
       //error, url is null
   }
   ```